# SQL Server HierarchyId: Moving Subtree Issue

Tags: sql-server, debugging, stored-procedures

I've created a stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SPNAME] 
    @UserCode INT, 
    @ReportsTo INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @HierarchyId HIERARCHYID
    DECLARE @NewParentHierarchyId HIERARCHYID
    DECLARE @OldParentHierarchyId HIERARCHYID
    SELECT  @HierarchyId = [Hierarchy]
    FROM    [aspnet_Users]
    WHERE   [UserCode] = @UserCode
    SELECT  @OldParentHierarchyId = [Hierarchy].GetAncestor(1)
    FROM    [aspnet_Users]
    WHERE   [UserCode] = @UserCode
    PRINT N'Old Root: ' + @OldParentHierarchyId.ToString()
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        SELECT  @NewParentHierarchyId = [Hierarchy]
        FROM    [aspnet_Users]
        WHERE   [UserCode] = @ReportsTo
        PRINT N'New Root: ' + @NewParentHierarchyId.ToString()
        PRINT N'Old HierarchyId: ' + @HierarchyId.ToString()
        SELECT  @HierarchyId = @NewParentHierarchyId.GetDescendant(MAX([Hierarchy]), NULL)
        FROM    [aspnet_Users]
        WHERE   [Hierarchy].GetAncestor(1) = @NewParentHierarchyId
        PRINT N'New HierarchyId: ' + @HierarchyId.ToString()
        UPDATE  [aspnet_Users]
        SET     [Hierarchy] = @HierarchyId.GetReparentedValue(@OldParentHierarchyId, @NewParentHierarchyId)
        WHERE   [Hierarchy].IsDescendantOf(@OldParentHierarchyId) = 1
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

I've hierarchichal data as follows:

```
  imirza10 (UserCode 1)
  -adil    (UserCode 3)
  --arif   (UserCode 5)
  ---saqib (UserCode 6)
  -farhan  (UserCode 4)
```

The above stored procedure was meant to move arif from adil to farhan.

When I executed the sp with the statement:

```
[aspnet_Users_ChangeHierarchy] 5, 4
```

It gives me following on the message tab of SSMS:

```
Old Root: /1/1/
New Root: /1/2/
Old HierarchyId: /1/1/1/
New HierarchyId: /1/2/1/
```

> *Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Procedure aspnet_Users_ChangeHierarchy, Line 48
>
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "hierarchyid":
>
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.HierarchyIdException: 24009: SqlHierarchyId.GetReparentedValue failed because 'oldRoot' was not an ancestor node of 'this'. 'oldRoot' was '/1/1/', and 'this' was '/1/2/1/'.
>
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.HierarchyIdException:
>
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId.GetReparentedValue(SqlHierarchyId oldRoot, SqlHierarchyId newRoot)*

Need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further testing I see the following issues in your query:

1. What the error message tells you is that you cannot reparent `@HierarchyId` from `@OldParentHierarchyId` to `@NewParentHierarchyId` because `@HierarchyId` is not an ancestor of `@OldParentHierarchyId` (you have calculated it to be the new path).
2. You use `@HierarchyId.GetReparentedValue` to calculate the new position instead of the actual value. This will give the same result for all rows.
3. You need to exclude `@OldParentHierarchyId` from the update.

The UPDATE query should look something like this:

```
UPDATE [aspnet_Users]
SET    [Hierarchy] = [Hierarchy].GetReparentedValue(@OldParentHierarchyId, @NewParentHierarchyId)
WHERE  [Hierarchy].IsDescendantOf(@OldParentHierarchyId) = 1 AND [Hierarchy] <> @OldParentHierarchyId
```

PS: I know I'm late on this question but it might help someone anyway.